# How to set SmartFilter entitySet

Tags: sapui5

When I try to filter something(smartFilter), I'm getting a 404 error, checking my payload I see that there is no entity in it:

```
GET null/$count?$filter=startswith(undefined,22) HTTP/1.1
```

this one is working

```
GET RfcSearchRequisitionsSet?$skip=0&$top=100&$filter=(Banfn%20eq%20%2722%27)&$select=Bsart%2cBanfn%2cBnfpo%2cWerks HTTP/1.1
```

XML

```
                <smartFilterBar:SmartFilterBar id="smartFilterBar"
                    entityType="RfcSearchRequisitions">
                    <smartFilterBar:controlConfiguration>
                        <smartFilterBar:ControlConfiguration
                            key="Banfn" index="1" groupId="_BASIC" width="300px"
                            visibleInAdvancedArea="true">

                        </smartFilterBar:ControlConfiguration>
                    </smartFilterBar:controlConfiguration>
                </smartFilterBar:SmartFilterBar>
                <smartTable:SmartTable id="smartTable"
                    entitySet="RfcSearchRequisitionsSet" smartFilterId="smartFilterBar"...>
```

Annotations

```
<Annotation Term="com.sap.vocabularies.UI.v1.LineItem">
<Collection>
<Record Type="com.sap.vocabularies.UI.v1.DataFieldForAnnotation">
<PropertyValue Property="Label" String="DocType"/>
<PropertyValue Property="Target" AnnotationPath="BSART"/>
</Record>
```

Comment: Maybe you provide at least the coding, where you create this SmartFilter ?

Comment: Sure, I've shared the xml

Comment: Which type of odatamodel you use? Is there correct metadata? Does this odatamodel is set as a default model for your view?

Comment: sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel, the oData is set as default, and I'm not sure about the metadata, but I don't know what to check

Comment: Is there any chance to run and debug this coding?

Comment: Nope, I've added the annotations, I think there is something wrong in it.

Comment: I don't think that even wrong annotation can lead to GET null/$count?$filter=startswith(undefined,22) HTTP/1.1 request. It looks that smarttable or smartfilterbar cannot take the needed configuration. Can you show your manifest.json file?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problems are with the annotations, they should be like:

```
<Record Type="com.sap.vocabularies.UI.v1.DataField">
    <PropertyValue Property="Label" String="DateCreated"/>
     <PropertyValue Property="Value" Path="Erdat"/>
</Record>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please copy below snippet in your controller and add the method to event "beforeRebindTable" in your SmartTable XML. Like: beforeRebindTable="handleBeforeRebindTable"

```
handleBeforeRebindTable: function(oEvent) {
        var mBindingParams = oEvent.getParameter("bindingParams"),
            aCustomFilters = [],
            sFilterValue = 22;  // it's an example, use your filter value

        // Getting filter parameters value
        if (sFilterValue ) {
            aCustomFilters.push(new sap.ui.model.Filter("Banfn", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.StartsWith, sFilterValue ));
        }

            var oOwnMultiFilter = new sap.ui.model.Filter(aCustomFilters, true);
            if (mBindingParams.filters[0] && mBindingParams.filters[0].aFilters) {
                var oSmartTableMultiFilter = mBindingParams.filters[0];
                // if an internal multi-filter exists of your smart table then combine custom multi-filters and internal multi-filters with an AND
                mBindingParams.filters[0] = new sap.ui.model.Filter([oSmartTableMultiFilter, oOwnMultiFilter], true);
            } else {
                mBindingParams.filters.push(oOwnMultiFilter);
            }

    },
```

Comment: Done that, nothing changes

Comment: I think you can stop count call using this snippet, as count is handled by the smart table itself. Use the code in init method of your component.js. 
                              
                              
              **this.getModel().setDefaultCountMode(CountMode.Inline);**

Comment: also define **"sap/ui/model/odata/CountMode"** above in your component.js

Comment: I'm not trying to get rid of the error, I need my smartFilter to work